# Is inline notation of f:uri.image broken in typo3 8.3.0?

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-8.x

I use the `TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor` to access FAL Images

```
dataProcessing {
    20 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
    20 {
        references.fieldName = image
        as = images
    }
}
```

the use of`<f:uri.image image="{images.0}" />` works fine but `{f:uri.image(image:'{images.0}')}` or `{f:uri.image(image:images.0)}`

gives me a FE Error:

> **#1: PHP Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in**
>   typo3_cms8/vendor/typo3fluid/fluid/src/Core/Parser/SyntaxTree/EscapingNode.php
>   line 41

Info: in 7.LTS the code works

Comment: If the code works and just throws a warning, I would ignore it and turn off the warnings. Actually there are a lot of warnings in Typo3 / Extbase like Array/String expected but got null, etc.

Comment: Please do not disable warnings. TYPO3 in general works without warnings if done correctly. Everything else is a real and valid bug and should therefor be fixed in the core system. Please report your issue with steps to reproduce at forge.typo3.org. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by two things in combination:

- The `{images.0}` variable is an object and has no `__toString` method
- The parameter is passed wrapped in a TextNode in the provided inline example

To correct this problem avoid wrapping the object accessor in a text node:

```
{f:uri(image: images.0)}
```

For a much more detailed explanation about this you can view my video about the subject: [Mastering Fluid - Accessing Variables](https://vimeo.com/167666466).

I should also add that we are indeed aware of this edge case of variables which are incompatible with strings being wrapped in a TextNode. So far the decision is that we would rather allow this edge case to slip through and avoid adding a condition that would need to check *every* variable in *every* template which cumulative would be billions upon billions of conditions with the single goal of avoiding this warning.